# Django image saved from base64 decoded string is corrupted

Tags: ajax, django, image, encoding, base64

I don't know what is wrong here, so I will describe the whole process:

First, I use [Croppie](http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) to let the user crop an image on the client side. This javascript library is supposed to return a valid `canvas` object encoded in base64. Then I send the image with `$.ajax()`:

```
croppie_div.croppie('result', {
            type: 'canvas',
            size: 'original',
            format: 'jpeg'
        }).then(function(resp){
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'recortar_carta_ajax' %}",
                method: "POST",
                data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}", 'imagen': resp, 'carta_id': "{{ carta_magicpy.id }}"},
                success: function(r){
                    alert(r)
                },
                error: function(r){
                    alert(r)
                }
            });
```

Then, I get the encoded string in django, decode it and save it to an `ImageField`:

```
if request.is_ajax():

        carta_id = request.POST.get("carta_id")
        imagen_b64 = request.POST.get("imagen")

        imagen_decodificada = base64.b64decode(imagen_b64)

        carta_magicpy = CartaMagicPy.objects.get(id=carta_id)
        imagen_django = ContentFile(imagen_decodificada, "imagen.jpeg")
        carta_magicpy.imagen.save("imagen.jpeg", imagen_django, save=True)
```

The saved image is corrupted. When I try to open it with a file browser I get the error:

> Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x75
>   0xab)

I don't know how to debug this. How can I find the error? Any advice will help.

This is the model:

```
def ubicar_magicpy(instance, filename):
    # Para ubicar las imágenes de magicpy
    path = "/".join([instance.grupo.nombre, "imagen.jpeg"])
    return path

class CartaMagicPy(models.Model):
    imagen = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=ubicar_magicpy)
```

Comment: From what I read here: http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/, Croppie returns a PNG as a default, which would explain why it can't be read as a JPEG. How about saving it with a PNG extension, does that work?

Comment: Hi @raphv . I will test that now. But, I do define the format to `jpeg` manually as the code above shows.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed that. Can you tell me if the result file is not empty? If it's empty, you have to make sure you are trying to use the same "flavour" of base64 (eg python's urlsafe_b64decode vs standard_b64decode) https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html

Comment: Ok, I tried removing the `jpeg` in format ... but then I get an "incorrect padding" error when decoding it. Also, going back to `jpeg` format the string after `base64.b64decode` looks like this: `s\�Ҥ�6�����S�|��#��mn4��W�77 ��V;�` . And the file is not empty, it weights 27kb.

Comment: Can you, on the client side, check the contents of the Croppie result? I think it still has the "data:image/jpeg..." part which you would have to remove at some point to make it a "valid" jpeg file?

Comment: Yes it does have that, it looks like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116591/discussion-between-raphv-and-alejoss).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the Base64 declarations, as they are not part of the base64 string themselves. You can do it either client side or server side, although the advantage of doing so server side is that if you decide to switch image formats, that string helps you determine which file format is being sent.

This is not the most elegant way of doing it, but you could have:

```
imagen_decodificada = base64.b64decode(imagen_b64.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,',''))
```